# How to write the presignup lands triggers for authorization and authentication using node js

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I m very new to aws lamda trigger and cognito user pool. I am trying to achieve the following things:

- I have two type of user (individual and organization).
- When I select individual it will store the value in dynamodb.
  And when I select organization it will store the data in different 
  dynamo dB.
- I have done  email and phone verification after verification it stored 
  in dB.
- I want to check whether the user is individual or from an organization.
- I am following the aws official lamda docs [AWS Lambda Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/) but unable to implement